# IntelliJ & SCSS compile - CSS does not change immediately

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, webstorm

Using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6

I'm using Grunt to compile SCSS files via [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass). Grunt watch, detects the change and compile has occurred. However CSS does not getting changed until I switch to another window and return.

How do see the change in the CSS immediately after compilation is done?

Comment: AFAIK IDE does not constantly check for file modifications that happen outside of IDE (3rd party app running in background -- `grunt --watch` or whatever). It checks for such external modifications of app focus change (when entering into app from another app) or when manually hitting `File | Synchronize`. The alternative is to use bundled File Watcher functionality to run such compilation -- if configured properly IDE will know what file to refresh after compilation is done.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43028590/783119 -- no comments from JetBrains members so far

Comment: Here is how this guy did it (using File Watcher): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31094262/783119

Comment: make sure to run Grunt from IDEA (using Grunt run configuration) - Idea normally synchronizes its VFS when task completes if it's run from the IDE